# How do I insert/escape a regex string to store in jsonb column?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I am using Postgres DB and I have a JSONB column. I am trying to insert a json node, which contains a regex , just for storage purposes.

here is the regex string (email validator):

```
^[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+↵)*@[A-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9-]+)*$
```

I am trying to insert this like so

```
  {
     "title": "Testing",
     "myregex": "^[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+↵)*@[A-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[A- 
   Z0-9-]+)*$"
  }
```

However, it keeps throwing error. How can I escape or otherwise get this regex string stored in jsonb?

Comment: And what is the error you get? You will at least need to escape the single quotes by doubling them, e.g `Arthur''s house'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that the string you are asking us to escape for your has already been escaped properly for this medium, so what I see as the string might not be what you want.  When I copied it from my screen, I got in the middle of it some weird carriage-return like thing or something else non-ASCII, which I removed.

Assuming you got the string into PostgreSQL accurately in the first place as text (for which I use dollar quoting), then the to_jsonb function will convert it into properly escaped JSON

```
select to_jsonb($JJ$^[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@[A-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9-]+)*$$JJ$::text);
                                             to_jsonb                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "^[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@[A-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9-]+)*$"
```

Now I don't know if what you see is what I intended you to see, because I might need to escape the escaping of the escapement, which might have been de-escaped incorrectly in the first place.  But the general principle should still apply.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in your keywords, seems to be that you want to insert directly via pgadmin. So, PostgreSQL have native JSON format support, I did an example in how to use this:

To show how you can store json objects, follows a dummy table:

```
$ CREATE TABLE test (id INT, data JSON, datab JSONB);
CREATE TABLE
```

Trying to check your string on the fly, on basic way. I'm saying to PostgreSQL to convert the string in json and access the `'title'` property:

```
test=# SELECT '{"title": "Testing"}'::json->'title';
 ?column?  
-----------
 "Testing"
(1 row)
```

Now, trying with your json (with some adjustments) - The backslash `\` and quote `'` are escaped here:

```
test=# SELECT '{"title": "Testing","myregex": "^[A-Z0-9_!#$%&''*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9_!#$%&''*+/=?`{|}~^-]+↵)*@[A-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9-]+)*$"}'::json->'myregex'
                                                              ?column?
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "^[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9_!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+↵)*@[A-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9-]+)*$"
(1 row)
```

So, to save, simply do the json conversion with escape strings:

```
test=# INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, '{"title": "Testing","myregex": "^[A-Z0-9_!#$%&''*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9_!#$%&''*+/=?`{|}~^-]+↵)*@[A-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9-]+)*$"}'::json);
INSERT 1
```

And, we're done.